# Elevation property is not working and URI is not registered

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm following a tutorial. The instructions are to make two base layout files. One that will be applied to all devices, and the other one will be applied to devices with an API level lower than 21 on top of the first base file. For a an API level of 21 or higher the instructions were to to make a folder within layout called layout-v21 that has another xml file. This file is identical to the base layout file for an API level lower than 21 except it has android:elevation="5dp". The background is also set so that can't be it.I've noticed that the xml in layout-v21 has it's property for the value xmlns:android= in red indicating an error. How can I fix this? Is this why elevation is not working properly? I'm not sure what I did wrong, I just want the elevation to work so I can move on. I have tried running with 21, 22 and 23 and I get the same result. No shadow.

layout/actitvity_main.xml -> The core layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:context=".MainActivity" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
                <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

layout/toolbar.xml -> For API of lower than 21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                                   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

layout/layout-v21/toolbar.xml -> For API of 21 or higher

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                                   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                   android:elevation="5dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

The property of the value xmlns for this has the URI error.

Here is my build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pluralsight"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I kid you not I figured this out as soon as I posted this. Checked my folder structure. The folder layout-v21 was inside of layout which is why elevation didn't work and I was receiving the URI error. I moved that folder to res and it worked. So moral of the story, check your structure.